# LARAVEL 4.2 NotFoundHttpException where my view name is correct

Tags: php, laravel

what is the problem? my route is correct, and view name is correct but i cant display my view. why?

//route.php

```
Route::get('register', 'HomeController@register');
```

//controller.php

```
class HomeController extends \BaseController {

public function index() {
    return View::make('index');
}

public function register() {
    return View::make('register');
}

}
```

// error log

```
[2015-11-13 09:42:21] production.ERROR: exception     'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in     C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php:5751
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(5073):     Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(5061): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(5053): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(7825): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(8432): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(8379): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(11088): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 C:\wamp\www\x\bootstrap\compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\wamp\www\x\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#11 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Do you have any other, working, routes? What does the log say?

Comment: @Jerodev the index which is '/' is working. added log

Comment: Can i see the form fields in your blade?

Comment: What happen if you return something inside your register function ? Like this `public function register() {
    return 1;
}`

Comment: @aldrin27 I tried to return "aaa" still gives me the same error

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen same error returned

Comment: @hahahaha Could you clear your views inside the folder `storage/framework/views` and try the request in incognito mode ?

Comment: Can I see your controller and views?

Comment: Is the name of the controller *ACTUALLY* `controller.php`? You can state by the stack trace that it's a problem related with routing, nothing to do with the contents of your controller file.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using a `compiled.php`, have you tried updating the file?
This can be done using the command `php artisan optimize`.

**Update:**
Can you put the class `HomeController` in a file named `HomeController.php` in the same directory? This is how all classes should be created because composer will load them this way.

After this, update the `compiled.php` again.

Comment: see my update. Try to put the classes in their own file.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

**I think I am bit confused to understand the question.**

`If you are trying to call your route from the controller then, you can user this answer.`

In this blow section of code, you are calling a view file (register.blade.php), it is not calling a route.

```
public function register() {
    return View::make('register');
}
```

If you want to call a route you need to do:

```
public function register() {
    return Redirect::to('register');
}
```

And that will be plus if you define your route as named route:

```
Route::get('register', ['as' => 'register', 'use' => 'HomeController@register']);
```

Then you can also call the route by its name:

```
return Redirect::route('register');
```

`If you are trying to call register function of HomeController, then you should check few things`:

- First make sure the name of your controller file is `HomeController.php`.
- Then try to update composer by `composer update` command
- Then load all classes by `composer dumpautoload` command
- And finally clear the cache by `php artisan cache:clear`

Hope these things may solve your issue.

Comment: I don't think that this is the point. The point is that the `HomeController@register` route isn't called when going to `/register`.

Comment: Hmm I think I had mad a mistake to understand the question :(

Comment: @Jerodev I have updated my answer, it might be helpfull